# How to disable code rearrangement in PhpStorm when reformatting

Tags: phpstorm, reformatting

In my project settings, I disabled all grouping and matching rules for `Code Style > PHP`.

When I reformat the code, my code is still rearranged. How can I disable this?

I've also disabled the confirmation popup when reformatting my code; how can I re-enable this?

@EDIT: I am using version 9 EAP PS-141.1306

Comment: What's your IDE version?

Comment: In v9, `Code | Reformat Code...`  (`Ctrl+Alt+L` on Windows using Default keymap) is no longer showing the reformat options dialog, at all. To see that dialog again -- you have to use different action -- `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L` on Windows using Default shortcut. For your OS/different keymap -- check your `Keymap` in Settings/Preferences -- it has search field. Action is called `Show Reformat File Dialog` and is located under `Other` branch.

Comment: P.S. You are not using v9.0.0 as it's not yet released. Better say that you are using v9 EAP and specify your build number (e.g. 141.1224) -- it's still work on progress so features may get added/removed/renamed etc.